# JPA entity relation in table which sharing same key as foreign and primary?

Tags: database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, one-to-one

Now, I have two tables.

1st Table (Object Table):

```
RefNo (PK) --> auto ascending
Type
Status
...
```

2nd Table (Object Detail Table):

```
RefNo (PK) --> FK reference from 1st Table
PolicyNo
DepNo
...
```

Entity for Object.

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long refnno;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "obejctTwo")
  private ObjectDetail objectDetail;

  private String type;

  private String status;
```

Entity for ObjectDetail

```
  @Id
  private long refnno;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "refnno")
  @MapsId
  private Object object;

  private String policyNo;

  private String depNo;
```

How can I save the Object using jpaRepository for Object which include ObjectDetail inside Object JSON but without knowing the reffno(PK) which is auto generated by db.

```
{
    "objectDetail": {
        "policyNo": "12345678",
        "depNo": "ABC"
    },
    "type": "new",
    "status": "pending"
}
```

Comment: You can use @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: I've tried this, but still cannot.
Error message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "OBJECTDETAIL_PK".

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to cascade the saving with the annotation `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` in the class `Object`?

I would then create the two objects with the available details, set the relationship and save the class `Object`.

```
object.setObjectDetail(objectDetail);
objectdetail.setObject(object);
repository.save(object);
```

The key of `object` would be set automatically and `objectDetail` would get the key from `object`.

## Edit: Entity Example

I was slightly surprised that the code did not work. Therefore, I implemented this for myself. It works perfectly with Spring Boot version `2.3.2.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Your issue might be `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "obejctTwo")` because this mapping does not exist.

### Object

```
@Entity
public class Object {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long refnno;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "object",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private ObjectDetail objectDetail;

    private String type;

    private String status;

    public setObjectDetail(ObjectDetail objectDetail) {
        this.objectDetail = objectDetail;
        objectDetail.setObject = this;
    }

    // Getters and remaining setters...
}
```

I added a slightly modified setter for `objectDetail` which helps to keep the bidirectional `OneToOne` mapping synchronised.

BTW: I changed the datatype of `refnno` to the object `Long`. Classes are considered to be better for database entities because than you can test them properly for null. Furthermore, this id can then be used for a `JpaRepository<Object, Long>`.

### ObjectDetail

```
@Entity
public class ObjectDetail {

    @Id
    private Long refnno;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "refnno")
    @MapsId
    private Object object;

    private String policyNo;

    private String depNo;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

### Repository and Execution

I created a simple repository.

```
public interface ObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Long> {
}
```

I then used the `save(Object entity)` method to persist a new `Object` with a new `ObjectDetail`.

```
Object object = new Object();
object.setType("new");
ObjectDetail objectDetail = new ObjectDetail();
objectDetail.setPolicyNo = "999";

object.setObjectDetail(objectDetail);

objectRepository.save(object);
```

Comment: seems not working. Since refnno in objectDetail is PK and we don't know the refnno when saving to the repository.
Error message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: @JeffreyChu I tried it and it worked. I added my code in the answer. Your issue might be your wrong mapping `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "obejctTwo")`.